# Apple Universal Links on private web server

Tags: ios, ios-universal-links

I am trying to get Universal links to work with my Xamarin iOS app and a private web server.
I am installing the app using an Ad Hoc profile together with https://www.diawi.com/ and it works except for the universal links.

I have placed the link in a Word doc.

However, in the IIS log, there is no request for the apple-app-site-association file when I install the app.

Also, the file swcutil_show.txt collected via sysdiagnose does not contain an entry for my app.

The log file contains this:

```
swcd[239] <Error>: Error getting enterprise-managed associated domains data. If this device is not enterprise-managed, this is normal: Error Domain=SWCErrorDomain Code=1701 "Failed to get associated domain data from ManagedConfiguration framework." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Failed to get associated domain data from ManagedConfiguration framework., Line=250, Function=<private>}
```

However, this entry is present even if I turn off Associated domains in Entitlements.plist.

And of course, the link opens in Safari instead of in my app.

Questions:

1. Do Universal links and associated domains work when the web server
   is not public?
2. Is it a problem that my device is under MDM?
3. Can I use diawi.com for installation and still expect universal
   links to work?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes to all questions.

The reason it did not work was because of a missing setting where Entitlements.plist had not been selected in Properties.